# Magento 2: Use of map in RequireJs-config

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, requirejs, requirejs-config.js

Is anyone know the use of this 'custom' & when we need to use that?

```
var config = {
     map: {
         **'custom':** {
                 '@@@': '@@@',
                 '@@@': 'js/@@@'
             }
         }
 };
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found some details about it & i have also tried to implement that which working fine.
'custom'
Is a module name ( for an example: Magento_Catalog ) that we can add here so our JS file we can used only for that module.

Thanks

Comment: But we can also give the "*" symbol instead of the module name right ?

Comment: Yes, if we use "*" then we can use this js everywhere.